# Please help identify a short horror story about religious freedom

Tags: story-identification, horror

I am seeking a short horror story (may be almost more of an apocalyptic tale, I guess, but it would have been in a horror/fantasy anthology) I read in the past few years. I don't believe the anthology would have been published before 2000.

The story is about an America where religious freedom is lost in the name of safety. The most notable part to me was a quote in it where the President talks about stepping off the freedom road for just a little while to restore the country back to its Christian roots. Dissenters were sent to education camps, which were torture/execution sites.
I think I recall a scene where there is a family at the dinner table and they are having to pray to Jesus, even though the parents don't want to and the children don't understand why.

I have tried searching on variations of this and come up empty.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? There might not be a lot to go on at this point (this is a characteristic of a lot of stories). The “freedom road” quote is pretty helpful, though.

Comment: How is it a horror story? What form does the horror take?

Comment: @user14111 sounds pretty horrific to me...

Comment: @user14111 I wasn't joking, as it happens. I see your point tho.

Comment: How is this specifically science fiction or fantasy? This might be better suited to [Literature.se].

Comment: @Mithrandir it's _speculative_ fiction, the umbrella SF and F both fall under.

Comment: @SQB: Eh, I suppose I could see it either way, but as it is, this one doesn't pass the sniff test for me, although I can't swear that it isn't because the subject matter is distasteful to me. That happens sometimes.